# TypeError: Cannot read property 'launchImageLibrary' of null

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have tried all the solutions online for this error. I am unable to open the image gallery.

```
<Button
    onPress={() =>
      ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(
       {
        mediaType: 'photo',
        includeBase64: false,
        maxHeight: 200,
        maxWidth: 200,
       },
        response => {
           console.log(response);
           setPhoto(response);
          },
        )
     }
       title="Select Image"
/>
```

Solutions I have tried:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
```

tried to change the import and how I call the `launchImageLibrary`

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
// import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';
```

Unfortunately I have not found a solution that works? Any ideas?

Comment: The fix was to 
```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
```
Then clean the build and rebuild the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix was to

```
rm -rf node_modules 
npm install 
cd ios 
pod install 
cd ..
```

Then clean the build and rebuild the app.

Answer (score 1):

My temporary solution after updating to Android SDK 33 is to upgrade react-native-image-picker to version 5.0.0 and use react-native-permissions package to handle READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34921466)

Answer (score 0):

You could stop the server and run the App with

`react-native start --reset-cache`.

So you don't have to reinstall all your modules.